# "sc.include" tag in Sitecore web.config

Tags: .net, sitecore

Can someone explain me how "sc.include" works? Can use it to include custom config files and handle it as usual custom section in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sc.include is mostly used internally by Sitecore. You can work with included configuration files (explained [here](http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2009/05/working-with-webconfig-include-files-in.html)), and you can also add your own custom handlers as per standard ASP.NET rules (your own configuration handlers).

Comment: Can you we use this Sitecore feature to add more complicated settings (like XML node with subnodes)?

Comment: Well... in theory I guess you could add whatever you like in here, but since this functionality only sits in the <sitecore> configuration branch maybe there wouldn't be much point. If you need that level of configuration, perhaps writing your own standard asp.net configuration handler is the best approach.